# Creating the issue with assigning the customer as the reporter with Jira API?

Tags: php, api, jira, jira-rest-api

I would like to create new customer if it does not exist and create new issue setting **this customer as reporter** in PHP with Jira API.

I create new customer using API ‘servicedeskapi/customer’ with POST fields ‘fullName’ and ‘email’ and then I create new issue using API ‘api/2/issue’ with parameters ‘fullName’ and ‘email’ of parameter ‘reporter’.

I am trying do this in this way:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');

$postvars = array('fields' => array('project' => array('key' => 'AP'), 'summary' => $body, 'description' => $body, 'reporter' => null));

$postvars['fields']['issuetype'] = array("id" => '10108');
$postvars['fields']['reporter']['fullName'] = $name; //POST field of customer's name to set customer as the reporter of new issue
$postvars['fields']['reporter']['email'] = $email; //POST field of customer's email address to set customer as the reporter of new issue

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://jira-address/rest/servicedeskapi/customer');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json', 'X-ExperimentalApi: opt-in'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
json_encode(array('fullName' => $reporterName, 'email' => $email))); //POST fields for creating new customer
$r = curl_exec($ch); //sending request for creating new customer
echo json_encode(json_decode($r), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); //printing response of request for creating new customer

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://jira-address/rest/api/2/issue/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postvars));
$r = curl_exec($ch); //sending request for creating new issue
echo json_encode($postvars, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); //printing POST fields of the request of creating new issue
echo json_encode(json_decode($r), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); //printing the response of the request for creating new issue
```

If the customer does not exist, the response is:

```
{
    "name": "kamilszmit2@live.com",
    "key": "kamilszmit2@live.com",
    "emailAddress": "kamilszmit2@live.com",
    "displayName": "kamilszmit2",
    "active": true,
    "timeZone": "Europe\/Warsaw",
    "_links": {
        "jiraRest": "https:\/\/jira-address\/rest\/api\/2\/user?username=kamilszmit2%40live.com",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "https:\/\/jira-address\/secure\/useravatar?avatarId=10122",
            "24x24": "https:\/\/jira-address\/secure\/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10122",
            "16x16": "https:\/\/jira-address\/secure\/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10122",
            "32x32": "https:\/\/jira-address\/secure\/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10122"
        },
        "self": "https:\/\/jira-address\/rest\/api\/2\/user?username=kamilszmit2%40live.com"
    }
}{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "AP"
        },
        "summary": "test",
        "description": "test",
        "reporter": {
            "fullName": "kamilszmit2",
            "email": "kamilszmit2@live.com"
        },
        "issuetype": {
            "id": "10108"
        }
    }
}{
    "id": "11187",
    "key": "AP-351",
    "self": "https:\/\/jira-address\/rest\/api\/2\/issue\/11187"
}
```

The customer and the issue are created but the **customer is not set as reporter of the issue**. The same problem occurs if customer already exists and when only the parameter ‘fullName’ or ‘email’ of the parameter ‘reporter’ is used.

What am I doing wrong? **How to create Jira issue with the customer as the reporter?** Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via REST, I have managed to set the reporter by using the `name` parameter, instead of `fullname`.

```
"fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "AP"
        },
        "summary": "test",
        "description": "test",
        "reporter": {
            "name": "kamilszmit2"
        },
        "issuetype": {
            "id": "10108"
        }
```

Other things I would check:

- The Reporter field is added to the Create Issue screen
- The credentials these calls are run with, have **Modify reporter**
  project permission (You will run into 405 error if they do not have
  this permission)